# Visual Studio source window and Bootcamp keyboard mapping

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, remap, bootcamp

So I recently bought myself a MacBook Air and I just installed Visual Studio 2012 in bootcamp. The problem now is that the key } is missing from the keyboard layout for some reason. The { key is mapped as ctrl + alt + 7, and since ctrl + alt + 0 was not mapped for anything I downloaded [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) and remapped } to that key combination. This works in every application except Visul Studio source window.

Can anyone tell me a way to fix this? Or maybe some other program that doesn't have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause myself. The keybinding was already mapped by default in Visual Studio as view.ViewCode, so I went into Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and removed that keybinding and it my } now works perfectly!